# Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.[SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79ayl.jpg)

> I facing this while running a react native app in windows, using android studio, I have connected my real device for running that usb via android studio **PLEASE HELP**

[PROJECT FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yEx5UzeC0Ci76HfKjxg6Mbxs1nVgMpgM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried this `npx react-native start` command?

Comment: yes sir I have tried its not working

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this? @DigitLake

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps
1st step : yarn install
2nd step : npx react-native start

inside project folder

3rd step : yarn start

4th step : npx react-native run-android

also update gradles in android Studio

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach didn't work for me. Getting the same error.

Comment: For some reasons if your android app requires internet and internet is not on on the virtual or real device you might be getting this error

Answer (score 0):

When running on a physical device you will often need to run the adb command:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

This will allow your device to communicate with the Metro instance.